# Efficiently Get Random Numbers in Range on GPU

Tags: random, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

Given a uniformly distributed random number generator in the range [0, 2^64), is there any efficient way (on a GPU) to build a random number generator for the range [0, k) for some k < 2^64?

Some solutions that don't work:

```
// not uniformly distributed in [0, k)
myRand(rng, k) = rng() % k;

// way too much branching to run efficiently on a gpu
myRand(rng, k) =
    uint64_t ret;
    while((ret = rng() & (nextPow2(k)-1)) >= k);
    return ret;

// only 53 bits of random data, not 64. Also I
// have no idea how to reason about how "uniform"
// this distribution is.
myRand(doubleRng, k) =
    double r = doubleRng(); // generates a random number in [0, 1)
    return (uint64_t)floor(r*k);
```

I'd be willing to compromise non-uniformity if the difference is sufficiently small (say, within 1/2^64).

Comment: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper

Comment: @isti_spl I'm not looking for a binary vector. I'm looking for a number in the range [0, k).

Comment: if you have a rng(n) that gives uniform random distr. in  [0, n-1], then rng(n)%k isn't uniformly distributed? Just how 'uniform' do you need them? maybe run some tests to see the resulting distributions?

Comment: It's not. Consider the case where you have a 2-bit RNG and you need a number in the range [0, 3). You get the same hazard with a 64-bit RNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two options: do the modulus (or the floating point) and settle for non-uniformity, or do rejection sampling with a loop. There really isn't a third option. Which one is better depends on your application.

If your *k* is typically very small (say, you're shuffling cards so *k* is on the order of 100), then the non-uniformity is so small that it's probably OK, even at 32 bits. At 64 bits, a *k* on the order of millions is still going to give you a non-uniformity vanishingly small. No, it won't be on the order of 1/2^64, but I can't imagine a real-world application where a non-uniformity on the order of 1/2^20 is noticeable. When I wrote the test suite for my RNG library, I deliberately ran it against a known bad `mod` implementation and it had a really hard time detecting the error even at 32 bits.

If you really have to be perfectly uniform, then you're just going to have to sample and reject. This can be done pretty fast, and you can even get rid of the division (calculate that `nextPow2()` outside the rejection loop--that's how I do it in [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib)). FYI, the fastest way to do the next-power-of-two mask is this:

```
mask = k - 1;
mask |= mask >> 1;
mask |= mask >> 2;
mask |= mask >> 4;
mask |= mask >> 8;
mask |= mask >> 16;
mask |= mask >> 32;
```

Comment: I was assuming a compiler which does CSE, and CPUs (idk about GPUs) tend to have a `bsr` instruction which make `nextPow2` two instructions. Anyhow, what if my k is generally in the range [2^63, 2^64-1)?

Comment: Then you're going to have a rejection rate on the order of 50%.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that returns 53 bits of random data, but you need 64, call it twice, use the bottom 32 bits of the first call for the top 32 bits of your result, and the bottom 32 bits of the second call for the bottom 32 bits of your result. If your original function was uniform, this one is too.